# UltraNumericEditor allows values larger than MaxValue setting

Tags: user-controls, infragistics

Using infragistics UltraNumericEditor, if I set the `.MaxValue` to 50, the control will allow me to enter decimals larger than the limit (for example, 50.99)

I see the same behavior if I set the `.MaxValue` property to 50.01 (can set values larger)

I can obviously resolve this in code but resetting the value, but it seems like the control should do this on its own.

Is there something I'm missing in how to use these properties correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a result of the `IEditorDataFilter` for percentage values.

Infragistics recommends, and I had implemented, an `IEditorDataFilter` which converts decimal percentages (.5 = 50%) into percentages for display.

This filter is applied before the validation for the control takes place. Therefore, setting the `MaxValue` to "50" allowed me to enter "50.99" but not "51"... normally this would have caused a validation error as per Steve's answer. However, because of the `IEditorDataFilter` applied to this control, the value was automatically converted to .5099 and this new value does not violate the constraint.

The solution I implemented was to check the value in the `Validated` event to see if it was larger than the `MaxValue` / 100, and if so to set it equal to the same.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are using the UltraNumericEditor with the property Style set to Decimal (or Double).
In this case the control allows you to insert digits that render the input invalid with respect to the property MaxValue. However, by default, you are not able to exit the control until the value is correct.
If you want, you can use the event **ValidationError** that gives your the ValidationErrorEventArgs parameter. This parameter contains the LastValidValue property to reset the wrong value, the RetainFocus to let your user exit from the editor (or, if you prefer, display an error message)

```
private void ultraNumericEditor1_ValidationError(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
{
    // Reset the content to the last valid value and allow the exit from the editor
    ultraNumericEditor1.Value = e.LastValidValue;
    e.RetainFocus = false;


    // In alternative display a message, but leave the wrong value to be reedited
    // DisplayValidationMessage("The max value allowed is 50.00");
}
```

Comment: no validation error is raised, the code enters the `Validated` event, carrying to erroneous value.

Comment: That's strange. Have you changed other properties? Which version are you using of the Infragistics suite?

Comment: I think I've stumbled on my answer... This is representing a percentage and I'm using an `IEditorDataFilter` to divide the user input by 100. The control's input is masked to allow me to enter 50.xx, but at the `Validation` event, the data filter has already taken effect, so .50xx does not violate the `MaxValue` constraint!